# Adding overlay while doing precise cut in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay

I have long video files that I would like to cut on precise timestamp and also I need to add watermark. Before I needed to add watermark I have used this command and it worked great:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:20.480 -i "INPUT.mp4" -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:11:39.960 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -filter:v "scale=1280:-1" -preset slow -crf 25 "OUTPUT.mp4"
```

But now I need to add watermark. I tried to use overlay filter (which uses second input file). I use apng file format to achive transparency:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00.680 -i "INPUT.mp4" -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:11:39.759 -i overlay.apng -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "crop=in_w-8:in_h-8,overlay,scale=1280:-1" -preset slow -crf 25 "OUTPUT.mp4"
```

Unfortunately in this case ffmpeg ignores second -ss switch. Without this switch there is no precise cut. Even if I give proper timestamp to first -ss switch there would be some frame freeze when playing first few seconds of a video file.

I came with some ugly quick fix by chaining two ffmpeg process, like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15.640 -i "INPUT.mp4" -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:11:39.800 -c:a copy -c:v huffyuv -f matroska - | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -i overlay.apng -filter_complex "crop=in_w-8:in_h-8,overlay=y=main_h-overlay_h:x=0,scale=1280:-1" -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 25 "OUTPUT.mp4"
```

In this case the whole encoding performance drops by 30%.

My goal is to do cutting and adding watermark in the single command. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option order matters. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Description

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00.680 -i "INPUT.mp4" -i overlay.apng -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:11:39.759
       -filter_complex "[0]crop=in_w-8:in_h-8[a];[a][1]overlay,scale=1280:-1"
       -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 25 "OUTPUT.mp4"
```

It's not clear what you meant to apply the crop to. I assume it's the first input since that's currently how ffmpeg is handling with your present command. If not, feed `[1]` to crop and `[0][a]` to the overlay.